# MS MVC3 Model Binding an Object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, object, modelbinders, defaultmodelbinder

Can someone help me better understand the DefaultModelBinder and how it handles binding a Model that has a property of type object?

I've downloaded the code and tried tracing through it, but am still scratching my head a little.

Let's say I have a Model like this:

```
public class MyModel{
    public object MyProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

And assume that my forms are all generated correctly (ex: name="MyModel.MyProperty")

What happens for various cases of MyProperty actually being set to instances of certain types?

In my case, I derive a custom binder from DefaultModelBinder and override CreateModel() to return a MyModel with MyProperty set to the correct Type.

I notice that if I set MyProperty to a string, then for some reason DefaultModelBinder::BindProperty(), returns a string[] of size 1 with the contents of the form field, rather than just a string. Why?

If MyProperty is some more complex type, even though my form fields are all named properly (ex: name="MyModel.MyProperty.FirstName") the binding doesn't seem to work at all.

Has anyone dealt with a complex/abstract model binding scenario like this before? Is there a better way? (I know it's weird, but I really do need to have MyModel's MyProperty be object because I can't know what Type it actually is until runtime)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an interface and use a custom binder for it. Is this possible? Then there is no unknown object type at runtime.