# MVC Model Binding subclass object property filled with a string array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a base view model with an Id property of type object (so I can have it be an int or a Guid) like so:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel
{
    public virtual object Id { get; set; }
}
```

And the view models thus derive from this

```
public class UserViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

My HTML then is rendered as:

```
<input id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="240" />
<input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="John" /> 
<input id="LastName " name="LastName " type="text" value="Smith" />
```

And when submitted to the MVC action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditUser(UserViewModel model)
    {
       ...code omitted...
    }
```

The values for the model properties are:

```
Id: string[0] = "240"
FirstName: string = "John"
LastName: string = "Smith"
```

My question is, why am I getting a **one item string array** as the value for **Id**, rather than just a string? And is there a way to change this behavior? It causes problems when I try to parse it into the expected type.

Comment: Try checking if you have two items with the same name. When this happens, values are sent as array to the server

Comment: This question is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809159/ms-mvc3-model-binding-an-object, though it has no answer, the OP found the same issue: getting arrays mapped onto a property defined as `object`

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving this with a custom model binder that handles the "Id" object property as a special case:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
        // apply the default model binding first to leverage the build in mapping logic
        base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);

        // since "Id" is a special property on BaseViewModel of type object, 
        // we need to figure out what it should be and parse it appropriately
        if (propertyDescriptor.Name == "Id" && propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof(object))
        {
            // get the value that the default binder applied
            var defaultValue = propertyDescriptor.GetValue(bindingContext.Model);

            // this should be a one element string array
            if (defaultValue is string[])
            {
                var defaultArray = defaultValue as string[];

                // extract the first element of the array (the actual value of "Id")
                var propertyString = defaultArray[0];
                object value = propertyString;

                // try to convert the ID value to an integer (the most common scenario)
                int intResult;
                if (int.TryParse(propertyString, out intResult))
                {
                    value = intResult;
                }
                else
                {
                    // try to convert the ID value to an Guid
                    Guid guidResult;
                    if (Guid.TryParse(propertyString, out guidResult)) value = guidResult;
                }

                // set the model value
                propertyDescriptor.SetValue(bindingContext.Model, value);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with typing your id property as `object` -- not sure how the default binding is supposed to work here, but since an object is potentially anything -- like a complex object with multiple properties itself -- perhaps it attempts to dump all of the properties it finds there into an array?

If the `Id` is not always going to be an integer, I'd suggest typing this as string, since the model-binding mechanism should have no problem mapping virtually anything sent over HTTP as string, so:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel
{
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a great idea but I cannot use it as I use expression trees to bind the viewmodel to the entitymodel and it won't allow int to string bindings. Otherwise I'm sure this would work well.